# Array of IDs as fetchAll parameter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have the following function:

```
public function findByIds($ids = array())
{
    return Database :: fetchAll('SELECT * FROM foo_bar WHERE test = 0 AND id IN :ids', array(
        array(':ids', $ids)
    ));
}
```

But it doesn't work of course. The $ids variable has the following structure:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(3) "101" } [1]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(3) "102" } [2]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(3) "110" } }
```

How can I match my query to find only rows specified by ids from my array?

Comment: What does that mean its not working. What is the error?

Comment: It's just wrong, I can't substitute string with array. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does @Uchia s answer not work?

Comment: you have to catch the array **values** in an array and search with IN

Comment: Are you getting any error while using my answer @KarolHernik